# what is the easiest way to migrate wordpress site from localhost to live server

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, server, localhost

I am traying to migrate wordpress website from localhost to live server using "all in one wp migration" plugin. From local server export is completed. but import from server is not completed. it shows 100% and waiting for 2/3 hours. see pics. What is the possible error for this longtime waiting/hang.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: I would read one of the many tutorials on the subject and pick the one you like best

Comment: Just copy and paste the changed files. or the theme

Comment: You could dump the mysql database and migrate to the server. Same for the files.

Answer (score 0):

In Wordpresss, All-in-One WP Migration Plugin is one of easiest way to make site live from localhost

https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/

This plugin exports your WordPress website including the database, media files, plugins and themes with no technical knowledge required.

In below video , there is proper explanation how we can Export and Import a WordPress blog using All in One WP Migration

[Howto: Export and Import a WordPress blog using All in One WP Migration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BpWxCeUWBOk&t=20s)

Answer (score 0):

[Duplicator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) is one of the best plugins to migrate an exact copy of your website.